# Calculating mean and variance in python

Tags: python, variance

I have this code to calculate mean and variance as you input a set of numbers, but my variance is off from what it should be. Is my variance formula off somehow or is it possibly some error in my code?

My output:

```
Input a positive number: 1
mean is  1.0 variance is  0

Input a positive number: 2
mean is  1.5 variance is  0.125

Input a positive number: 3
mean is  2.0 variance is  0.3958333333333333
```

Correct output:

```
Input a positive number: 1
mean is  1.0 variance is  0

Input a positive number: 2
mean is  1.5 variance is  0.5

Input a positive number: 3
mean is  2.0 variance is  1
```

```
mean = 0
variance = 0
x = 0
n = 0
while x >= 0:
    x = float(input('Input a positive number: '))  # user input for code
    n += 1
    if x < 0:
        break

    if n == 1:  # Added this if statement to avoid dividing by 0
        mean = x
        print('mean is ', mean, 'variance is ', variance)
    else:
        mean = mean + ((x-mean)/n)  # formula for calculating mean
        variance = (((n-2)/(n-1)) * variance) + (((mean-x)**2)/n)  # formula for calculating variance
        print('mean is ', mean, 'variance is ', variance)
```

Comment: python2 or python3 ?

Comment: You cannot compute the value of variance based on the previous variance value, at least not this way. The thing is that the formula for variance depends on the *current* average of the list items, and the previous variance was depending on the *previous average*. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: use `np.mean` & `np.variance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for variance is wrong. You can find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775391/can-i-calculate-the-new-standard-deviation-when-adding-a-value-without-knowing-t) the formula for better understanding, I am not explaining here.

```
mean = 0
variance = 0
x = 0
n = 0
while x >= 0:
    x = float(input('Input a positive number: '))  # user input for code
    n += 1
    if x < 0:
        break

    if n == 1:  # Added this if statement to avoid dividing by 0
        mean = x
        print('mean is ', mean, 'variance is ', variance)
    else:
        mean = mean + ((x-mean)/n)  # formula for calculating mean
        
        variance = (((n-2)/(n-1)) * variance) + (((x-mean)*(x-pre_mean))/(n-1))  # formula for calculating variance
        print('mean is ', mean, 'variance is ', variance)
    pre_mean = mean
```

Output:

```
Input a positive number: 1
mean is  1.0 variance is  0
Input a positive number: 2
mean is  1.5 variance is  0.5
Input a positive number: 3
mean is  2.0 variance is  1.0
Input a positive number: 4
mean is  2.5 variance is  1.6666666666666665
```

You give a wrong test case,

```
Input a positive number: 3
mean is  2.0 variance is  0.1
```

Here, variance will `1 not 0.1`. You can easily check the sample variance using [online calculator.](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/statistics/variance-calculator.php)

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. Looks like my formula was a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list to store all the input.

```
x = 0
data = [] 
while x >= 0:
    x = float(input('Input a positive number: '))  # user input for code
    if x < 0:
         break

    data.append(x)        
    N = len(data)
    mean = sum(data) / N

    var = 0
    if N > 1:
        a = [x - mean for x in data]
        a = [x**2 for x in a]
        var = sum( a) / (N-1)
    
    print( "mean is ", mean, " variance is ", var)
```